# Installing landscape-server > ERROR landscape-setup superuser

Tags: server, package-management, landscape

I installed landscape yesterday without any problems, and then I broke it because I had to change my hostname and a bunch of other configurations on apache.

I made the mistake of removing the packages trying to do a "clean install" using the landscape-server-quickstart and now I'm stuck at the error below.

I've deleted the landscape group, user, data from postgress, config files, but just can't figure it out.

`apt-get install` output:

```
apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
landscape-server-quickstart is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
**Setting up landscape-server (15.01.3-0ubuntu2) ...
========================================================================
Attempting schema upgrade as requested.
WARNING: this could take several minutes or more.
========================================================================
2015-08-12 19:37:38 INFO landscape-setup Bootstrapping from service.conf file ...
2015-08-12 19:37:38 ERROR landscape-setup 'superuser'**
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: error processing package landscape-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of landscape-server-quickstart:
 landscape-server-quickstart depends on landscape-server (>= 15.01.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package landscape-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package landscape-server-quickstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 landscape-server
 landscape-server-quickstart
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the setup log:

```
Aug 12 16:37:38 landscape-setup INFO  Bootstrapping from service.conf file ...
Aug 12 16:37:38 landscape-setup ERR  'superuser'
```

Here is the `service.conf`:

```
cat service.conf
[combo-loader]
base-port = 9070
threads = 10

[job-handler]
mailer = queue
mailer-path = /var/lib/landscape/landscape-mail-queue

[api]
mailer = queue
mailer-path = /var/lib/landscape/landscape-mail-queue
base-port = 9080

[maintenance]
mailer-path = /var/lib/landscape/landscape-mail-queue

[scripts]
mailer-path = /var/lib/landscape/landscape-mail-queue

[pingserver]
base-port = 8070

[message-server]
base-port = 8090
access-log = message-server_access-%(instance)s.log
oops-key = DM%(instance-letter)s

[landscape]
access-log = appserver_access-%(instance)s.log
oops-key = DF%(instance-letter)s
reprepro-binary = /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/reprepro-wrapper.sh
mailer-path = /var/lib/landscape/landscape-mail-queue
repository-path = /var/lib/landscape/landscape-repository
secret-token = 

[package-upload]
root-url = http://localhost:9100
threads = 10
mailer = queue
stores = main account-1
port = 9100
mailer-path = /var/lib/landscape/landscape-mail-queue

[load-shaper]
good-duration = 60.0
critical-load = 10.0
good-load = 3.0

[package-search]
account-threshold = 800
stores = main package resource-1
port = 9099
pid-path = /var/run/landscape/landscape-package-search-1.pid

[broker]
vhost = landscape
host = localhost
password = b64:a25Gam4yOW9iRFJwS2tTSA==
port = 5672
user = landscape

[stores]
user = landscape
host = localhost

[schema]
```

Comment: I was able to get pass this section by installing landscape-server into a vm and exporting the postgres database and importing it into my broken server... now need to figure out the startup scripts that are not present

Comment: ok found the solution, had to reinstall everything from scratch manually, I did not use the quickstart, there is a very good manual guide here https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ManualInstallation15.01

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I removed the packages instead of purging them and that mess up with Landscape config files and database. So I've decided to do the manual installation that can be found here: [LDS Manual Installation](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ManualInstallation15.01)

This end up to be a more elegant and clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo pg_createcluster 9.3 main --start
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```